# Mule ESB read @Value property outside Callable class

Tags: java, spring, mule, mule-esb

How to read **@Value** property **outside** the class that implements the Callable interface at MuleESB? In my case the **some_property**:

- is not null at onCall method in the MainClass (ok)
- is null at foo() methid in the ClassB (wrong)

How can I get this value in the foo() method? I don't want to pass it as a parameter.

```
public class MainClass implements Callable {

    @Value("${some_property}")
    String some_property;

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {      
        System.out.println(some_property); //some_property is ok
        ClassB obB = new ClassB();
        obB.foo();// some_property inside this method is null
    }
}

public ClassB {
    @Value("${some_property}")
    String some_property;

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(some_property); 
    }
}
```

**EDIT: some more information about my problem**

My MuleESB project contains a resource file located in the following file:
/MY_PROJECT/src/main/resources/services.properties
It contains some values like

```
some_property = AAAA
another_property = BBBB
```

This file is refferenced in one on my flow.xml files: 
/MY_PROJECT/src/main/app/common.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:services.properties"
        order="4" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

I want to use this config in another flow. I have Java component there an a class that implemments the Callable interface

```
public class MainClass implements Callable {

    @Value("${some_property}")
    String some_property;

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {      
        System.out.println(some_property); //some_property is ok
        ClassB obB = new ClassB();
        obB.foo();// some_property inside this method is null
    }
}
```

I have second class ClassB that will be often used. I want to run use it within previously mentioned onCall() method from MainClass

```
public ClassB {
    @Value("${some_property}")
    String some_property;

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(some_property); 
    }
}
```

I want to load some_property value from my services.properties file. I use the following code

```
    @Value("${some_property}")
    String some_property;
```

I want to read this value only in ClassB foo() method. But there is null now (instead of MainClass onCall() method where the value is set). ClassB is independent and may be used in several onCall() methods so I don't want to read this properties in the MainClass and pass them to ClassB constructor or methods. How can I achive this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve and why? It is not completely clear. Could you please clarify the question a bit? Your motivation is not completely clear, so we can't really help. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AttilaBujáki Thank you for your response. I've added more details to the question.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap "${some_property}" into a MEL block and write: "@Value("#{'${file-path}'}")"? If this a system propery then you can also access it via "System.getProperty("some_property")". For details see the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a constructor to read the props file. If you are creating many ClassB objects you may want to change this read the file once, rather than on each new instance.

```
public ClassB {

    String some_property;

    public ClassB() {

        Properties p = new Properties();
        try {
            p.load( this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("your-props-file.properties") );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        some_property = p.getProperty("some_property");
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(some_property); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the best solution because I handle only one file reference here.

Answer (score 0):

please try this using method injection, and you can now call MainClass.some_property outside.

```
public static String some_property;

@Value("${some_property}")
public void setSome_property(String prop) {
    some_property = prop;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to acces that property in the main class. I'd like to read it only in ClassB (MainClass does not contain some_property).